# tomcat not displaying images

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, jhipster

It is a jhipster project (spring boot, angularjs).
Images are not being displayed in prod profile on production server.
The application is installed as ROOT on tomcat 8.

In the dist folder the image names are automatically changed during deployment, adding some random number prefix & a dot to the image name (869cf845.hipster.jpg).

on removing the prefix and correcting the path reference to match it, the image starts showing (hipster.jpg).

I want that the images should show automatically. Can someone help with this?

Comment: When you say "the image names are automatically changed during deployment" : Is this done manually or by some software ?

Comment: My build process is being handled by maven & grunt.js. The images are minified and renamed for cache automatically. Primarily I want to know that the image name generated by the build process is being referenced correctly in html, still the image is not being displayed. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jhipster project keep your own html files in scripts/entity/ folder only. 
During deployment any html files within scripts will be fixed by grunt tasks to change the name of the images to something like 869cf845.hipster.jpg instead of hipster.jpg.

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to give more info, so that people can instantly help you. Your dist is probably produced by an automatic process, I guess an ant script. The random prefix you spotted is added by this script and this procedure is called 'image revving'. It is primarily used, so that users can download updated images from servers, where images are cached. You have to be cautious though, since if you revision the images on every deployment (withouth them being updated), users will have to download all the images, even though they are not updated. In other words, you lose the benefits provided by cache mechanisms.

Now, if you have revving enabled in you ant script, you can also enable paths renaming in css and html files with the following settings :

```
css.rev.images = true
html.rev.images = false
```

You can see the commit for the implementation of image revving in https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/commit/1dd6e816a3363f22eb597890accedd0b218c7b65

However, you can simply serve all the images as static content from a folder outside your application. In this way, images will not be involved in the build process and if any image is updated, you will manually update it in this folder. To learn more about this method, a good source is https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/

Comment: Thanks for the insight. My build process is being handled by maven & grunt.js. Primarily I want to know that the image name generated by the build process is being referenced correctly in html, still the image is not being displayed. Why could that be?

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you a straight solution, since the information regarding the problem are few (server, technologies, logs etc). It probably has something to do with the server configuration. You can request the revved images and check the logs in order to find the reason why the server fails to serve the image.

Comment: The Question was clear and after a few days I was myself able to solve it by hit and trial.